# variables aren't updated in lambda c++

Tags: c++, vector, lambda

I'm new to c++ and I am using lambdas in one of my projects. But my project isn't working because my variables are not updated in the lambda. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {1,2,3}; //declaring vector with 3 elements
    
    auto lambda = [vec]{ //declaring the lamba
        for(auto i:vec){ //looping through every item of the vector as i
            cout<<i<<endl; //outputing i followed by a new line
        }
    };
    
    lambda(); //outputs 1 2 and 3
    
    vec.push_back(4); //adding 4 to the vector
    
    lambda(); //still outputs 1 2 and 3. why isn't the 4 outputed?
}
```

Please help me solving this problem. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: *'the vector'*, nope there are two vectors here.

Answer (score 4):

You capture a copy of the vector, but you want a reference:

```
auto lambda = [&vec]{  // <---- reference capture
    for(auto i:vec){
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
};
```

A lambda is short hand for a class with `operator()` and members for the captures and an instance of that class. When you capture `vec` then the instance of that class has a member that is initialized by copying `vec`. When you capture the vector by reference then that member is not a copy.

Answer (score 1):

`[vec]` is capturing the vector by value. A copy is created.

Capture by reference using `[&vec]` if you want it to be updated.